# How to change font size of .doc document all paragraphs using spire.doc dll in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

In my application, I need to load .doc application for change font size. It's working for single paragraphs but when i need

to change entire paragraphs font size it is not working for all paragraphs.

I tried the below

```
Section s = document.Sections[0];
            int i = s.Paragraphs.Count;
            ParagraphStyle style = new ParagraphStyle(document);

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {              
                Spire.Doc.Documents.Paragraph p = s.Paragraphs[j];

                style.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Times New Roman";
                style.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 20;
                document.Styles.Add(style);
                p.ApplyStyle(style.Name);
            }
```

The above is not working how can i change font size for all paragraphs entire document where i did mistake in loop can anyone please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change word entire document font size using spire.doc dll in c# windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642101/how-to-change-word-entire-document-font-size-using-spire-doc-dll-in-c-sharp-wind)

Comment: @Berkay it is not a possible duplicate but an exact duplicate. I've seen Jhon post this question for the 3rd time now.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find any so i posted again and again

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not running is that you did'nt setup `style.Name`.
You need to setup `style.Name` to get recognized by `p.ApplyStyle(style.Name);`